# Binary Classification of a ship Dataset

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, clustering, image-classification, image-recognition

What are the best options for a big dataset classification?
I am thinking of 2 solutions-

1.**Autoencoders**

2.**PCA**(Principal Component Analysis)

I think the first approach is better.Does it works for my problem?Or maybe someother solution is better?

Thank you

Comment: Just use a Convolutional Neural Network.

Comment: @Gerry P  can you give me a sample of what you mean?Thank you

Answer (score 1):

**None** of the methods you described may classify a dataset alone whereas **both** can be used to transform your data into another domain in an unsupervised fashion.

**PCA** projects your data onto n-orthogonal components. A trained **encoder** (first component of the autoencoder) can project your data onto a latent space.

**Both** of those representations can be used in conjuction with a classifier, such as a decision tree, to form a classification pipeline.

There is no globally best solution, try them both for your specific problem. PCA is, in my opinion, way faster to try out using sklearn instead of building your own autoencoder using PyTorch or Keras. Give PCA a first go and if the results are poor, try using an autoencoder.

Comment: @picko1  thank you for your answer i would like to see if someone has something else to say

Comment: This is a great answer. While the autoencoder can give you a better result in the end, it is not fore sure and takes more time. In my experience performance is often similar, but it is very dependent on the domain. Be aware that PCA is not robust against outliers though. Training an autoencoder is also quick so you should definetly compare them :)